# How do I make cooldown display in mins:seconds | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

cooldown makes it so that bot when there is a cooldown the bot shows the cooldown timer in seconds. I want to make it so that the bot shows it in mins:seconds. Not sure how to do it though.

This code has a cooldown of 5mins

```py
  @rob.error
  async def rob_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
          await ctx.send("Member doesnt exist")
      if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
           embed = discord.Embed(
              title="Your on a cooldown!", color=discord.Color.blue())
      embed.add_field(
          name="\u200b",
          value=
          f"Slow down will ya?\n Wait for {round(error.retry_after)} seconds"
      )
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the amount of seconds, you can easily calculate the amount of minutes using `division (//)`, and the remaining seconds using `modulo (%)`.

```
>>> x = 83
>>> minutes = str(x // 60)
>>> seconds = str(x % 60)
>>> print(f"Minutes: {minutes} | Seconds: {seconds}")
Minutes: 1 | Seconds: 23
```

Then, if you want to, you can add a leading zero to them if necessary

```
def leadingZero(time: str):
    if len(time) > 1:
        return time

    return "0" + time
```

In order to make "1:3" show up as "01:03".

This would make your code end up looking like this:

```
@rob.error
async def rob_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Member doesnt exist")
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You're on a cooldown!", color=discord.Color.blue())

        cd = round(error.retry_after)
        minutes = str(cd // 60)
        seconds = str(cd % 60)

        embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value=f"Slow down will ya?\nWait for {self.leadingZero(minutes)}:{self.leadingZero(seconds)}.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def leadingZero(self, time: str):
    if len(time) > 1:
        return time

    return "0" + time
```

Also, I see you didn't actually put your `add_field` and `ctx.send` inside of the `is_instance` (it's *below* it), might want to tab those in. Lastly, it should be `You're on a cooldown`, not `Your`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me with my Economy Bot!